# Android Auto Custom Actions split between cards

Tags: android-auto

I am playing around with adding android auto to my app.
The documentation i have found is somewhat lacking, and i am trying to put 3 custom actions on the primary card and two on the secondary card.

I have added my 5 custom actions in order of appearance , thinking this would automatically put the last two on the secondary card. since there are only four spots including the pay button on the primary..

but instead it puts only the first two on the primary card and the rest on the secondary.  I have tried adding more, only to find the same result.  2 on the primary, and the rest on secondary..

Can someone point me in the right direction.  i must be missing a flag or something

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this correctly, but just know that all primary Actions are already defined in the `PlaybackStateCompat` that, you use when creating `PlaybackStateCompat.Builder`. But when you add custom actions via `PlaybackStateCompat.Builder.addCustomAction()`, AndroidAuto UI behaves in following manner.

In main Consumption View:

**Scenario 1:** With Play, Next and Previous Buttons, position for your customs actions (From left):

1= Custom Action 1
2= Previous Track
3 = Play/Pause
4 = Next Track
5 = Overflow button if you have more than 2 Custom Actions or Custom Action 2.

**Scenario 2:** Only a Play button from default actions and NO Next and Previous Buttons, position for your customs actions (From left):

1= Custom Action 3 (To the left of Action 1)
2= Custom Action 1 (Moves closer to the center)
3 = Play/Pause
4 = Custom Action 2 (Other Side of play button)
5 = default is empty, Overflow button if you have more than 4 Custom Actions else your Custom Action 4.

In Secondary Consumption View:
As soon as count of Actions increases more than 5, **Action number 5** (the right most one) is assigned to back/toggle action ([reserved action](https://designguidelines.withgoogle.com/android-auto/audio-apps/main-consumption-view.html#main-consumption-view-secondary-action-card)), such that any more actions are now placed in following manner(**Left to Right on screen**):

1 = Custom Action 5 
2 = Custom Action 6 
3 = Custom Action 7
4 = Custom Action 8
5 = Custom Action 9

I have recently understood this placement of actions with an app experiment I was working on.
I will post some screenshots in future if possible. happy coding!

Comment: it would be helpful if you can provide example of code as well, please i really need this, as i am not able to find out the solution for the same.

Comment: @Anmol Sure I will try to share the answer as soon as possible, I currently do not have access to my laptop. Rest stay assured, this will work.